# Rsa decrypt message (n,e)

Tags: encryption, rsa

How to decrypt message

modulus => n

```
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
```

public exponent => e

```
010001
```

message

```
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
```

code [here](https://pastebin.com/jKr7z2rA)

I trying to use

```
openssl base64 -d | openssl rsautl -inkey key.pem -decrypt message
```

But this return nothing. So please help to decrypt this message

Answer (score 3):

> So please help to decrypt this message

This would appear to be an RSA encrypted message, using a 4096 bit RSA key.  Assuming that the key was generated properly, then it is infeasible to recover the plaintext using only the message and the public key; sorry...

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin: if you're asking whether it can be a 24 bit value, no, it'll be much larger than that.  If you're asking if it can start with the hex digits `fa807e`, well, it might, but it won't be larger than $n$ (unless someone deliberately selected a larger-than-necessary private key)

Comment: but can it be the same public and private keys? Maybe there are online tool where i can insert keys and get decrypted text?

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin: nope; RSA uses distinct private and public keys.  As for an online tool, where you can put into the public key and the ciphertext,  and get the plaintext, no, it doesn't exist; 4k RSA is believed secure.

Comment: But what is the Wiener method its says can decrypt message